# error: getting a passing "***" as "this" .... discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

The compiler is telling me I can't make the assignment in the constructor. I have extremely similar code in another class and it compiles just fine.

#### Dependency.h

```
class Dependency {
public:
    Dependency(std::function<void ()> const & func);

private:
    std::function<void ()> const call_back;
};

Dependency::Dependency(std::function<void ()> const & func){
    call_back = func;
}
```

Comment: The actual error text would be nice to have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dependency::Dependency(std::function<void ()> const & func){
            call_back = func;
}
```

First, this constructs a `Dependency` object, and it's `call_back` member.  Then it enters the `{}`, which attempts to reassign `func` to `call_back`, which isn't allowed, because `call_back` is const.

Instead, we have to tell the compiler to construct `call_back` with `func` the first time, which uses this magic syntax:

```
Dependency::Dependency(std::function<void ()> const & func)
:call_back(func)
{
}
```

You use the same technique to call a specific constructor for parent classes.  Please note that it ignores the order you use here, the compiler will instead always construct the parent class(es) first, and then the members in the order they were declared in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

A `const` member can't be assigned after initialization. You have to ensure it is properly initialized in the constructor initialization list.

```
Dependency::Dependency(std::function<void()> const& func) : call_back(func) {}
```